# Where does blockchain data come from if there are no peers?

Tags: ether, synchronization, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm still having problems syncing.  I've kept my client up-to-date, I'm using an SSD, and I have 1Gbps/1Gbps internet service.  It just hangs with 270 blocks remaining forever.   The logs say:
`INFO [12-04|07:02:48] Imported new state entries               count=927  elapsed=2.955ms   processed=180886 pending=11412 retry=504 duplicate=119 unexpected=1210`

Anyhow, it's very frustrating for a lot of reasons.  Primarily and at this instant, I can't perform any transactions to handle my money.  I'm stuck.

To investigate further, I've setup the latest Ethereum Wallet on a fresh system and it does the same thing.  Hangs at around 200 blocks remaining.  Oh, and I noticed something interesting to me.  Initially, it connects to a dozen peers and downloads very fast.  When it hangs, it's obvious it will no longer download so I restart.   On restart, it connects to no peers, but if some time (a day or so) has gone by, there are enough blocks that it starts downloading again; however, it downloads blocks when there are no listed peers.

Where is it downloading blockchain data from when it has not connected to any peers?

Comment: You can just use "MyEtherWallet" to send wallets through your browsers for now, not sure why its stuck syncing, maybe someone else can help

Comment: @RononDex Thanks.  I'm beginning to understand well how Ethereum and Ethereum Wallet works, but it's been rough.  It seems to be way too early to trust much about it, especially with these failures from the very start.  What makes MyEtherWallet better?  It looks even riskier.  Am I understanding right, the site wants you to load your keystore files into the browser and then use the browser to enter your passwords to unlock your keystore files/wallets.  From what I've read, it's paramount to protect the keystore files and NOT give them to someone/site.

Comment: MyEtherWallet runs completly client side in the browser, no syncing and hard drive space needed. It's safe (as long as you check the URL and make sure you are actually on https://www.myetherwallet.com/ and not some phishing site. It's the most userfriendly and leight weight wallet to use imo. If you start getting more into the topic you can try to install your own node

Comment: I suppose it's a trust thing and I trust the Ethereum Wallet from the ethereum foundation more than a website that essentially says trust us, just load your keystore here, we won't POST it and capture your password.  However, I have to say my trust in Ethereum in general is wearing thin.  I am interested in building Dapps, and I do want to run a full node.  As I understand, I can do smart contracts with the Ethereum Wallet if NOT in fast mode; however, there is a difference between full/slow and not at all.  It's been over a day now on a clean system with latest and it just won't sync.

Comment: Anyhow, all of that aside.  Where the heck is it getting blockchain data from when it reports there are no peers? :P

Comment: Which wallet are you currently using?

Comment: If you want to make sure that for example myetherwallet does not send anything to the server, you can press F12 and go to the "Network" tab. You can see there what your browser sends to where

Comment: and to run a node you usually use geth. Are you on linux?

Comment: OS X and Ethereum Wallet from ethereum.org

Comment: the ethereum wallet already has a full node included (usually comes pre-bundled with geth). Basically if your wallet has to sync on start up, it also acts as a node